# Javascript/jQuery String issue with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having an issue in IE 8 where I'm trying to store a value from a form field select box using jQuery's val(). The String shows up fine in all browsers except IE 7/8 where it shows up as null. I'm assuming it has to do with the characters (quotes?) in the field, but I'm not sure how to work around this. Code below:

```
var $size = $("#size");
var size = $size.find('option:selected').val(),
```

The actual value of the selected field is:

```
L: 158.375" x 80.5" 4023mm x 2045mm
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What's not working? can you produce a non working cod at http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `#size` is the id of the select box, why are you using `find('option:selected')`? Whatever the currently selected option is will be the `val()` of the select element.

e.g. `$('select#size').val();` should return the value of the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the feedback. It appears it was a bug with an older version of jQuery (1.4.1). I've updated to 1.7.2 and it works correctly now.